# Did Rey and Kylo's bond accentuate this Force move they performed?

Tags: the-force, kylo-ren, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

In *The Rise of Skywalker*,

> Rey impales Kylo through the abdomen with his lightsaber at the end of their duel in Endor. This is certainly a mortal wound, but Rey then heals Kylo with little exertion and Kylo appears to be no worse for wear afterwards as he is able to immediately rush to Exagol and defeat the Knights of Ren in combat with little trouble.

Then, at the end of the movie

> after Rey dies, Kylo brings her back to life by exchanging his own life for hers.

Are they only able to perform these feats due to their unique status as

> a dyad in the Force?

It seems like an extraordinarily powerful ability that even the strongest Jedi and Sith masters of the past have never been able to do.

Answer (score 3):

It's very unlikely because this is by no means the only time Force heal is used in canon.

First of all, earlier in the film she healed an alien monster and explains to BB-8 that she transferred life force from her to the monster, presumably she would have been capable of transferring all of it but that would have been stupid. We can also assume that she and this monster were not a dyad.

Secondly, we also see 'Baby Yoda' use this power in the Mandalorian, and he presumably didn't have this kind of bond with the man he healed.

Last of all, we have Darth Plagueis, who allegedly could save others from death with the Force. Note however that this is different because he was *creating* life instead of transferring his own, so he didn't have to die to do this. Another difference would be that Palpatine only said he could save the ones he cared about, it's possible that he had to establish some sort of bond with someone (just by caring about them) but I think it's most likely that he could save anyone, regardless of whether he cared.

Comment: Those are minor wounds compared to Kylo being impaled (with a gaping hole in his torso) and Rey being actually dead.

Comment: @mai the point of the question was whether or not the dyad had anything to do with it. You could transfer your life to save someone else but die yourself without a dyad.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear wasn't their bond *as a dyad in the Force* that allowed Ben Solo to perform his self-sacrificial Force Healing trick, but rather it was their bond as special-super-BFFs. Simply put, he was willing to kill himself to heal her. Presumably this healing act would have worked on *anyone*, **had he been similarly motivated to risk his life to save theirs.**

> He knew exactly what Rey would do, in his place. It was the easiest decision he’d ever made.
>
> He cradled her gently and placed his hand on her abdomen. He closed his eyes. Called on the Force. **Ben didn’t have much strength left, and he was about to do something he’d never done before. Fortunately, Rey had shown him how to give.**
>
> **Ben poured everything into her. He found reservoirs he didn’t know he had. He gave her his whole self.**
>
> Her diaphragm rose with a breath, and her warm hand covered his. Her eyes lit up.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>